# Access to property in UserPrincipal

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have a DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal object.
I see using Visual Studio some properties in It but i could access to them.

[image]

How can I access to, as example, the property **EmailAddress**?
Is it posible?

```
member.Something.EmailAddress
```

?

**Update**

**EmailAddress** is not accesible directly:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `member.EmailAddress` ....

See [this MSDN page for a complete list of all properties on `UserPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal_properties.aspx) which you can access directly - and `EmailAddress` is most definitely one of them!

**Update:** you're saying you cannot access `.EmailAddress` directly... are you **really** dealing with an `UserPrincipal` object?

Try this:

```
UserPrincipal up = (member as UserPrincipal);

if (up != null)
{
   string email = up.EmailAddress;
}
```

Can you access the `.EmailAddress` property on the `up` object??

Comment: thanks but it is not one of the availables. Look at the image I just updated in the question.

Comment: @RicardoPolo What is the datatype of `member`, is it a `UserPricipal` or just a `Principal`? You may need to cast it.

Comment: @RicardoPolo: updated my response - can you try my suggestion?